# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home/u921305435/public_html/phpinfo.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql

I know this has been asked many times already, but me being thick, havent been able to solve it

Ive got this code and its giving me an error

```
<?
$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="databse";

mysql_connect("host",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = mysql_query($con, "SELECT ProductName FROM ProductTrans");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ProductName</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

What is the problem with it?

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT ProductName FROM ProductTrans")`

Comment: mysql_query($query,$connection)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ProductName FROM ProductTrans");
```

For more info on mysqli_query: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
OR if you want to use mysql_query() function which is deprecated you should do like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ProductName FROM ProductTrans");
```

for mysql_query() :https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: @ling.s: http://in2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on php.net:

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

You have the parameters swapped in your code in the call to mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

### It should be query followed by the connection. Interchange the parameters !

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ProductName FROM ProductTrans",$con);
```

---

**`Sidenote`** : Also, stop using `mysql_*` functions as it deprecated. Switch to **`PreparedStatements`** !

Answer (score 0):

you're using the syntax of mysqli_query with mysql_query. My advice is replace all your mysql with mysqli, as mysql_* is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
$con = mysql_connect("host",$username,$password); // SEE HERE 
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = mysql_query($con, "SELECT ProductName FROM ProductTrans");
```